# Solving linear congruences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am trying to solve $25x\equiv15\pmod{29}$

I multiply both sides by $7$ which makes the L.h.S congruent to $1x \pmod{29}$

From this I have that $7\times25x\equiv7\times15\pmod{29}$

I am really confused with where to go from here.  Some help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: As $175\equiv1\pmod{29},175x\equiv x$ and this $\equiv 105\pmod{29}\equiv18$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I have understood your answer below partially but i could not understand your comment... $175 x \equiv x$ and then.. could you please explain the rest

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, we have $$175x\equiv105\pmod{29}$$ Now $175\%29=1,105\%29=18$

Answer (score 1):

As $(25,15)=5$ and $(5,29)=1,$ we can immediately divide either sides by $5$ to get $\displaystyle 5x\equiv3\pmod{29}$

Multiply either sides by $6$ as  $\displaystyle 5\cdot6\equiv1\pmod{29}$

Comment: Okay, I understand that we can divide each side by 5, but how did you decide to multiply it by 6?  And wouldn't we then get $30 = 18 (mod 29)$?...so $x=18$..?

Comment: Seeing that $(25,15)=5$ and $(5,29)=1$ is crucial step in this... SO, I can cancel $5$ to get $5x \equiv 3 \mod 29$ but then.. :O

Comment: @user108949, your are right, see my comment in the question as well.Multiply by $6$ gives $30x\equiv18\pmod{29},$ but $30x\equiv x\pmod{29},$ so $\cdots$